# why am I getting runtime error for the following code and how to fix that?

Tags: c++, c++14

I was solving this problem on Codeforces [B. Ania and Minimizing](https://codeforces.com/contest/1230/problem/B) and I got runtime error on test 9. I am new to c++ and I did not understand why this happened. Could someone help me fix this error? Thanks :)

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    
    int n, k;
    string num;
    cin >> n >> k;

    cin >> num;

    if(n==1){
        cout << 0 << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if(k==0){
        cout << num << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if(num[0]!='1'){
        num[0]='1';
    }
    else{
        k=k+1;
    }
    for(int i=1; i<k; i++){
  
        if(num[i]!='0'){
            num[i]='0';
        }
        else{
            k=k+1;
        }
    }
    
    cout << num << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Here you can check the runtime error details:

https://codeforces.com/submissions/iwrestledthebeartwice at submission number: 85825935

Comment: Can you detail the run-time error?

Comment: If `num[0] == '1'` then there's an off-by-one error. In fact, there's another one with that `k=k+1` line too, I think.

Comment: @aafulei I added the link to the runtime error at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @KenY-N I did not understand your comment, could you please explain it with more details?

Comment: The first two lines -- `sync_with_stdio( false )` and `cin.tie( NULL )` -- seem to be superfluous...?!? You do flush your outputs with `endl`, and you don't use stdio... some kind of "habit"?

Comment: @jaychandra did you try to read the problem statement? You are missing a very basic check: `S has exactly n digits and doesn't contain any leading zeroes`. `k + 1` is just unnecesary, in both places.

Comment: @DevSolar I'm quite new to c++ and I don't know the real use of `sync_with_stdio(false)` most people use it in their code for faster inputs and outputs so I used it. Is it necessary to not use `endl` with that?

Comment: @Waqar yeah, I added a statement to check that and I still got runtime error on test 9

Comment: remove `k = k + 1` from everywhere. Then loop till `i <= k`. Make sure `i` stays less than `n`. Always. If `k > n`, you should exit without doing anything.

Comment: @jaychandra: After a bit of googling, I was mistaken as to what those calls actually do. `sync_with_stdio( false )` disables the synchronization of C++ streams with C I/O. That is a bit faster if you are using C++ streams only. `cin.tie( NULL )` disengages the sync between `cin` and `cout` (usually `cout` is flushed every time `cin` is queried for an input). Both are micro-optimizations that should not make a real difference in 99% of programs. It seems you are taking your hints from the "competitive programming" crowd... note that they have a lot of bad habits...

Comment: @Waqar I removed `k = k + 1` and put `i<=k && i<n` in the loop and also put an if statement to check `k>n` to exit. I then gave this input `5 3 51528` the output was `10008` instead of `10028`. what else should I do to fix this?

Comment: @DevSolar thanks for the suggestion I really appreciate that :)

Comment: @jaychandra `for(int i=1; i<k; i++){` -- Then you do this: `if(num[i]!='0')` -- However, `num` and the number of characters it really has, i.e. `num.size()` are not related to `k` in any way.  You are basically assuming you have `k` characters in `num`.  If anything that loop should respect both `k` **and** the number of actual characters in `num`.  `for (int i = 1; i < k && i < num.size(); ++i)`. or `int minLoops = std::min(k, num.size());  for (int i = 1; i < minLoops; ++i);`.  This is how you write defensive code -- so at worse you get a wrong answer, and not out-of-bounds access errors.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did as you told, here is the code https://pastebin.com/QZwWJepw at line 32 I put i < k instead of i <= k as you told but I am getting wrong output for the following input `2 2 102` I got `102` instead of `100` any idea why this is happening?

Comment: This is where you should be debugging your code by using the debugger that comes with your compiler toolset.  The original issue was the runtime error.  Programming is not just about writing code, it is also about knowing how to fix code that you wrote that happens to not work properly.

Comment: Thanks, @PaulMcKenzie I'll try to debug the code and if I found the error I'll let you know. :)

Comment: @jaychandra: You're welcome. Bottom line, you can now safely omit those two calls, unless you *know* they solve a problem you actually *have*. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all of you guys pointed out I fixed my code. I was dumb and making the loop go out of bounds.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int n, k;
    string num;
    cin >> n >> k;

    cin >> num;
    if(k==0){
        cout << num << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if(num.size()!=n){
        return 0;
    }

    if(n==1){
        cout << 0 << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if(k==0){
        cout << num << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if(k>num.size()){
        cout << num << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if(k>n){
        cout << num << endl;
    }

    if(num[0]!='1'){
        num[0]='1';
        k--;
    }
 
    for(int i=1; i<=k and i<n; ++i){
        if(num[i]!='0'){
            num[i]='0';
        }
        else{
            k=k+1;
        }
    }
    
    cout << num << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `k` is larger then the size of `num` (which could happen because you are incrementing it at line 37) you will get an "access out of bonds" Error at `num[i]='0'`.

For example you have the following inputs:

```
5 5
12345
```

This will cause line 33 to access memory past the size of `num`. now it depends if this memory is `0`, then your code will work. But if it is not zero you try to write a zero which is not permitted.

Answer (score 2):

Your code makes out of bounds string accesses on some inputs, for instance given n=2 k=1 S=10 you access num[2] which does not exist. This will cause the runtime error that you see.

Comment: Hey, I got runt time error for this input ```200000 187545
13019320000140860500034930083000900886000089050900000907267200506020180043050000007000395020800000000008041052304050009005000880300352005008008550262040100505000107400720806600186369550739967000000350020086001003000040800600507580400370005095800041020810006600060580004822680446000100700000006000700000030800640000308000006800007500000043220506086004009704800848025030000004006305070002000020000010058040408008000900058020570004285800208009250000006297000400004130001003707709000......``` I think, it's not because of out of bounds array

Comment: Why do you think that? Your code clearly has issues with out of bounds accesses. Maybe try fixing those and test again. If the error persists then I'll believe you. Given the simplicity of the code it's really hard to see what else could be causing a runtime error except an out of bounds array access.

Comment: I fixed the out of bounds issue as told by @Waqar and for the input `5 3 51528` I got `10008` instead of `10028`, how to fix that error. Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/QZwWJepw

Comment: @jaychandra A wrong answer is a different issue than what your original question is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem:

```
for(int i=1; i<k; i++){

    if(num[i]!='0'){
        num[i]='0';
    }
    else{
        k=k+1;
    }
}
```

You are reading and writing past the end of the buffer (buffer overrun). Supoose `n` = 3, and `k=3`. and the number is `1000`. You will find `0` in all positions and your `k` will be incremented on every iteration, making it `6` by the end. While the string was just `4` chars long. You read and wrote to a location which you are not allowed to. That is undefined behaviour.

To fix, you need to make sure you don't change `k` while you are looping as that is totally unnecessary. Also, make sure you read and understand the problem statement completely before attempting to solve the problem.

Let's remove the `k = k + 1` from both places and make sure we are always less than `n`. `i` needs to do at least `k` iterations

```
if(num[0]!='1'){
    num[0]='1';
}
for(int i=1; i <= k && i < n; i++){

    if(num[i]!='0'){
        num[i]='0';
    }
}
```

Additionally, if our first digit is `'1'`, we have one less `0` to replace, so we will decrement `k` by 1 in that case:

```
if(num[0]!='1'){
    num[0]='1';
    k--;
}
```

This will solve the issue and you will get correct output. You still need to place additional checks to make sure `num.size() == n` always and that `k < n` always.

Note that this might not be the most efficient or best solution, it only attempts to fix the issues you had with the logic you used.

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing out the issues in my code. The code got accepted, your code posted here is missing a condition. when it is in the loop if `num[i] != '0'` we make it `num[i]='0'` else we should increase k by 1 so that we don't have to reduce the k value, that is number of moves when inum[i] == '0'`. Anyway, thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Of course, the final logic should be yours as you are the one solving the problem. We can only help you with the issues you encounter along the way :)